# Wait until another process finishes

Tags: swift, function, asynchronous

I’ve got a problem with timing..

My application loads data into the tableview with function `loadData()`

And the user can post data with `postData()`

Both changes the tableView’s datasource + cells in some way. The functions are using web requests therefore they’re not on the main thread only the adding to the tableView part.

---

loadData() loads the datas from the database into the tableView

postData() saves the data to the database then adds it to the tableView

---

The problem is that very rarely but sometimes my app quits due to these two functions conflict: when the user Posts Data but it is currently Loading Data.

How can I prevent `postData()` until `loadData()` has finished?

And + prevent more than 1 postData()-s firing at the same time? Without using a lot of bools? Is there some common way?

Comment: Bools could have a lot of problems if not synchronized correctly, and if synchronized, you have performance penalty (but minor), you could also try spinlocks if you want, but I think it is a bit unsafe, so using Apple's API itself like Semaphores is safer, one should migrate from old threading to dispatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Semaphore, a semaphore indicates a rare resource is being used (which we here consider to be "data handling, which we only have one of it at a time").

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore.init(value: 1)
```

In `postData` and `loadData`, wait for the semaphore (when one is available, it enters, when nothing is available, wait until one is available).

```
func postData() {
    // Make even the waiting on background thread not to block the user
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        semaphore.wait()
        makeThePostData(completion: {
            semaphore.signal()
        })
    }
}
```

`loadData` should have structure like that also.

---

Also try to use reactive programming techniques, it is more modern